# Cheerio.js and working with subsets of the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cheerio

I've having some issues (probably misunderstanding soemthing most likely) when reading the dom and using cheerio.js to do so from with a simple node.js app.

I'm using request to grab the html from a website and cheerio to navigate it find certain portions.
As and example the html looks like this....

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr><td class="title"/>Title 1</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td class="dl">Some Name1</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td class="title"/>Title 2</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td class="dl">Some Name2</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td class="title"/>Title 3</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td class="dl">Some Name3</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

What want to do it find all instances of the **td** with class **title**
grab the title text and thne for each one of those then grab the name at the **td** with class **dl**.

So far

```
$('td[class=title]')
```

will get me all the **td** with that class and using the each function

```
$('td[class=title]').each(function(i, elem)
```

lets me grab the text from each but I want to grab the title then the next **td** with the **dl** class before moving on to the next title.

I guess what I'm really asking is can I get that td.dl element while in the 
$('td[class=title]'.each function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
  .each(function(){
     $(this).parent().next().find('td.d1').text()
   })
```